# SoapUI can't read WSDL

Tags: ssl, wsdl, soapui

I'm trying to open this URL via SoapUI:

https://mybilling.voipconsultants.biz/wsdl/CustomerResellerService.wsdl

I've tried downloading 4.5.1, however it still complains. It simply says

> "There was something wrong with the WSDL you are trying to import"

and that's it, no description of the issue. Can anyone help me get this parsed with SoapUI?

Comment: I get the same error, so in any case you are not alone...

Comment: Idem here and it's a shame.

Answer (score 3):

**Incorrect:**
<del>I might be wrong, but I'm not sure whether SoapUI can handle remote WSDLs (i.e. not stored as a local file on your computer).
Note: I'm using SoapUI 4.0.1</del>

Try downloading necessary files from: https://mybilling.voipconsultants.biz/wsdl/

Beside your WSDL you'll also need some additional files from there. (they are referenced from the WSDL)
If you don't have them you will get self-explaining error messages, like:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: .../Types.xsd
```

**Edit - moved from comment:**

You can get more detailed message by clicking error log on the bottom bar.
With this I get:

```
Mon May 20 07:59:29 CEST 2013:ERROR:org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: union value 
'unbounded' does not match any members of 'type of maxOccurs attribute in xs:narrowMaxMin' 
org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: union value 'unbounded' does not match any members of 
'type of maxOccurs attribute in xs:narrowMaxMin'
```

seems sth is wrong with xsd file.

Comment: It's definitely capable of fetching remote WSDLs without manually downloading them, and crawling for referential documents such as _Types.xsd_.  See [this URL](https://um.voipconsultants.biz:8443/wsdl.fcgi?get=Voicemail.xsd) for a working example (works for me anyway).

Comment: @quickshiftin You're right - the wsdl you provided works even with SoapUI 4.0.1.  My bad.  
  
You can get more detailed message by clicking `error log` on the bottom bar. With this I get `Mon May 20 07:59:29 CEST 2013:ERROR:org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: union value 'unbounded' does not match any members of 'type of maxOccurs attribute in xs:narrowMaxMin'
   org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: union value 'unbounded' does not match any members of 'type of maxOccurs attribute in xs:narrowMaxMin'`
seems sth is wrong with xsd file.

Comment: I would have upvoted your answer - if your comment had been part of the answer. You can edit your answer to include what you learned (and what you wrote in your comment).

Answer (score 2):

I came to this page from Google. In case someone else has the same problem I wound up having, my issue was in the WSDL itself. One of the elements was marked as `maxOccurs="unbounded"` inside of a `complexType` with an `all` -- in order to have more than one occurrence, the `complexType` must be a `sequence`.

My log had this error message:

`An error occurred [union value 'unbounded' does not match any members of 'type of maxOccurs attribute in xs:narrowMaxMin'], see error log for details`

Answer (score 0):

For me, the exception was a `com.eviware.soapui.impl.support.definition.support.InvalidDefinitionException`.

I was able to work around the problem by saving the WSDL to disk as XML with my web browser and opening that local file directly in SoapUI.

Comment: I tried this, but then I get an error that one of the files the WSDL refers to is not found. `Error loading [file:/Users/quickshiftin/Downloads/Types.xsd]: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/quickshiftin/Downloads/Types.xsd (No such file or directory)`. Did you do a recursive download or something?

Comment: No, the WSDL was a single XML file in my case (ending with `.asmx.xml`).

Comment: It's a single file for me as well, but then I just get the complaint I pasted in my last comment.